# Python. List comprehension. List in the list and so on

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is it possible do like that with list comprehension. For example, if I call function f4(5), it should show like: [[[[[]]]]]. So each time append empty list in previous list.

Comment: What is the aim to do that with list-comprehension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def f(x):
    if x == 1:
        return []
    return [f(x-1)]

print(f(5))
```

Output:

```
[[[[[[]]]]]]
```

Comment: It is called recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

You can append a list to itself, which since lists are mutable, sets off a recursion that leads to an infinitely nested list that can be indexed up until the recursion limit. Python uses the elipisis placeholder to display this:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.append(lst)
>>> lst
[[...]]
>>> lst[0][0][0][0][0]
[[...]]
```

However, I can imagine no practical use for this at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any real use for that, but of course it's possible.

```
def f(n):
 return [f(n - 1)] if n > 1 else []
```